# Grouped Collection View shows empty groups on iOS

Tags: ios, maui, observablecollection, mac-catalyst, grouped-list

I have a MAUI application with a view binded to a viewmodel containing a grouped `CollectionView` with these properties set:

```
        <CollectionView
           x:Name="MyList"
           VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
           ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionViewItemSourceGrouped}"
           SelectionMode="Single"                   
           SelectedItem="{Binding MyItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
           SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding MySelectionCommand}"
           RemainingItemsThreshold="2"
           RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand="{Binding LoadMoreItemsCommand}"
           IsGrouped="True"
           EmptyView="No item found.">
```

I get and group the source items from an awaitable Web api and I correctly get the collection grouped when I first navigate into the view and if I start toggling back and forth the switch filtering the list. Unfortunately, when I navigate into a detail page and back to the collection through Shell navigation, if I act on the switch again and I reload the list I always get a number of empty groups and it graphically results into a big mess.
The object used as a source for the collection is `CollectionViewItemSourceGrouped`, it is an `ObservableCollection<ItemsGroup>` which has this implementation:

```
public class ItemsGroup : ObservableRangeCollection<ItemModel>
{
    public DateTime Date { get; private set; }

    public ItemsGroup(DateTime date, ObservableRangeCollection<ItemModel> list) : base(list)
    {
        Date = date;
    }
}
```

Here's also how the data are loaded:

```
        try
        {
            if (InLoading)
                return;

            InLoading = true;

            //Selectio item gets blanked
            if (MyItem is not null)
                MyItem = null;

            CollectionViewItemSourceGrouped = new();

            paginationIndex = 1;

            IEnumerable<ItemsGroup> grpItems = await LoadItemsSub(0, MaxItemsPerPage);

            if (grpItems != null && grpItems.Any())
                CollectionViewItemSourceGrouped = new ObservableRangeCollection<ItemsGroup>(grpItems.OrderByDescending(s => s.Date));
            else           
                CollectionViewItemSourceGrouped = new();
        }
        catch (LocalException ex)
        {
            UIMessagesManager.ShowMessage(Stringhe.DANGER, ex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            AppCenterEventManager.TrackError(ex, string.Empty);

            UIMessagesManager.ShowMessage(Stringhe.DANGER, Stringhe.UNKNOWN_ERROR);
        }
        finally
        {
            InLoading = false;
        }
```

Every time I reload data, I make sure the object `CollectionViewItemSourceGrouped` is set to `null` or is a new empty object. I would expect the collection to be empty, rather this keeps on showing empty groups with only the header set. How can I get rid of them and let the collection properly refresh?

**This only happens on iOS and MacCatalyst. It nicely works on Android and WinUI.**

[image: Here's a pic of what I get once I reload data coming back from a detail page.]

In the image above, the header 01/05/2023 is unexpected and appears as an empty group. But the item source has already been reassigned properly in the view model.
Here's what I expect:

[image: Expected behavior in reloading the list]

I tried literally everything but with no luck on iOS and MacCatalyst.

**UPDATE 1**

Here's a GitHub public repository with a sample project. Try to execute it on iOS Simulator and you will be able to see this strange behavior when `VerticalOptions=FillAndExpand` for the `CollectionView`. [See picture]

[image: Wrong rendering for groups on iOS]

[GitHub Repository - GroupedCollectionSample](https://github.com/ImproveSoftware2022/GroupedCollectionSample/tree/main/GroupedCollectionSample)

**UPDATE 2**

Notice that if I set `VerticalOptions` for the container (`StackLayout`) I keep on getting the same "empty" group headers odd behavior. I currently "solved" leaving the `StackLayout` and setting a fixed `HeightRequest` to the `CollectionView`, but of course it doesn't fit to all devices.

I also tried to set it into a `Grid` as suggested and here's the code. This doesn't fix anything because the collection keeps on expanding out of the screen and so the scroll to the bottom becomes impossible (I think due to the fact that the container doesn't have a fixed end). I dunno what to do since: changing the container `VerticalOptions` causes the issue, leaving it at default causes the `CollectionView` not to scroll to the bottom.

```
<StackLayout>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Heigth="40" />
            <RowDefinition Heigth="*" />  
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        
        <StackLayout
            Grid.Row = "0"
            HeightRequest="40"
            Orientation="Horizontal">
            
            <Switch
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                Margin="10,0"
                IsToggled="{Binding FilterData}">
                <Switch.Behaviors>
                    <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
                        EventName="Toggled"
                        Command="{Binding FilterDataCommand}" />
                </Switch.Behaviors>
            </Switch>

            <Label 
                Text="Only enabled users"/>
        </StackLayout>

        <CollectionView
            x:Name="ListUsers"
            Grid.Row = "1"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ListUsersGroup}"
            SelectionMode="Single"                   
            SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentUser, Mode=TwoWay}"
            SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding OpenDetailCommand}"
            IsGrouped="True"
            EmptyView="No user found.">

            <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="extModels:UsersGroup">
                    <Label
                        Padding="10,8"
                        BackgroundColor="Gray"
                        TextColor="Black"
                        Text="{Binding Date}"
                        FontAttributes="Bold"
                        FontSize="15"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="extModels:User">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Label
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Margin="20,0"
                            Text="{Binding FirstName}">
                        </Label>

                        <Label 
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Text="{Binding LastName}" >
                        </Label>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </Grid>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: 1. Its best to mark image to show exactly what is wrong. Is it the header row `01/05/2023`?  You could also add a 2nd image, showing what it should look like. 2. Show the code where you reload the data. 3. Try setting `CollectionViewItemSourceGrouped` only *after* you've added any data. Prepare data in a local variable: `var newSource = new ObservableCollection<ItemsGroup(); ...add groups to newSource... CollectionViewItemSourceGrouped = newSource;` Does that work?

Comment: Thanks @ToolmakerSteve for your advice on how to improve the question, I added the requested information to help you have the complete picture. I also tried your suggestion but I still get the same behavior on iOS and MacCatalyst. What drives me crazy is that Android and WinUI are working like a charm with exactly the same code!

Comment: Does `grpItems` include the empty group? Maybe the working platforms are smarter about skipping empty groups.

Comment: Not at all! In the highlighted case, it only contains 1 group with its 3 children. So there's no automatic empty group exclusion. When I first open the view, everything gets designed smoothly but it changes once I navigate into (and back from) a detailed page (such as the one that can be reached through the '+' icon on top right) with Shell navigation. I come back into `ApplyQueryAttributes` but without performing any operation on the list. From that moment on, acting on the switch and reloading data would cause the list to have that strange design with empty groups. I can't figure it out!

Comment: @ImproveSoftware you are, for some reason, stripping a lot of relevant code. I do not care for the reason, but If you want help, you should put something that can be reproduced at least to some extent.

Comment: @ImproveSoftware, it does sound like there is some inconsistency in Maui’s internal UI state, after returning from a detail page. I recommend making the simplest project you can that reproduces the problem, making a public github repo, and creating a new issue at `github maui issues`.

Comment: @H.A.H. just tell what else you need in the code to be helpful. The entire procedure is quite complex to be totally shared. So if you need any specific portion of code, I am available to give them to you.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve thanks for the hint, unfortunately though it’s quite complicated to set up the entire infrastructure to reproduce the matter on a new project. So if there’s no way to workaround it, maybe forcing the refresh of the UI state, I will be abandoning the groups.

Comment: *"... set up the entire infrastructure"* - The point is to make the **simplest** project that shows the symptom. Should NOT be dependent on any infrastructure. Remove everything that can be removed, yet problem occurs. If the cause is what it appears to be, then all you need is two "hardcoded" sets of data, included in the code. One with two groups, the other with only one. Show the first, go to detail page, come back, show the second. If that works correctly, then we are on the wrong track as to the cause in your project, and should ask further questions. If it fails, then it is indeed a bug.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Thanks a lot for your patience! I reproduced the same setting on an empty template project. The issue seems to be related to this: if I remove the VerticalOptions=FillAndExpand from the CollectionView properties, those facade groups don't appear. Doing this, btw, my CollectionView doesn't scroll to the end. I have updated my question with the public GitHub repository where to find my brand new project. On Simulator, after several steps of navigation I was able to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not have time to review everything, but this here:

```
<StackLayout>
        <StackLayout
            HeightRequest="40"
            Orientation="Horizontal">
            
            <Switch
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                Margin="10,0"
                IsToggled="{Binding FilterData}">
                <Switch.Behaviors>
                    <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
                        EventName="Toggled"
                        Command="{Binding FilterDataCommand}" />
                </Switch.Behaviors>
            </Switch>

            <Label 
                Text="Only enabled users"/>
        </StackLayout>

        <CollectionView
            x:Name="ListUsers"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ListUsersGroup}"
            SelectionMode="Single"                   
            SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentUser, Mode=TwoWay}"
            SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding OpenDetailCommand}"
            IsGrouped="True"
            EmptyView="No user found.">
```

This is more than enough...
What are you "filling"? How are you filling something, that has no bottom?

Also, you see now, how "more code provided" makes much more sense. In your original question, because I did not see the parent, I could not notice this.

Edit: Limiting the height of the item in the container, is one way. Now, usually you will want to limit the container itself.

In your scenario, A `Grid`, with `RowDefinitions= "40,*"` will give you the desired result. (first row 40, second row, as much as it takes). This way, you can place your `StackLayout` in `Row = 0` , and `CollectionView` in `Row = 1`, and let them take all the space.

(So this way your design will be working on different phone screens.)

EDIT2:

```
<StackLayout> <<< This here has no height restriction. Delete this.
<Grid> <<< This will match your view. Keep it.
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Heigth="40" />
        <RowDefinition Heigth="*" />  <<< this here reads "fill"
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
    <StackLayout
        Grid.Row = "0"
        HeightRequest="40"
        Orientation="Horizontal">
        
        <Switch
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            Margin="10,0"
            IsToggled="{Binding FilterData}">
            <Switch.Behaviors>
                <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
                    EventName="Toggled"
                    Command="{Binding FilterDataCommand}" />
            </Switch.Behaviors>
        </Switch>

        <Label 
            Text="Only enabled users"/>
    </StackLayout>

    <CollectionView
```

Comment: What do you suggest then? Consider that even setting `VerticalOptions = FillAndExpand` on the `StackLayout` and removing it from the `CollectionView` would result in a odd behavior, since it would not scroll to the bottom and rather would jump back.

Comment: Lets start by replacing VerticalOptions with HeightRequest = 456? Shall we?

Comment: You mean on the `CollectionView`? Sorry if I ask but I’m quite new to MAUI and some behaviors are different from Xamarin.

Comment: Yes. Limit the Height of the CollectionView. Replace VerticalOptions with HeightRequest. See what happens, then we will talk again.

Comment: When you see the difference, try the method I described in the Edit. It is used to make your design responsive.

Comment: If I set `HeightRequest` to some value, it will finally work. Sorry to mention that changing the `StackLayout` to a `Grid` as you suggested, won't cause the odd behavior to disappear. This appears to be a bug! I can workaround it setting the `HeightRequest` to a value that would almost fill the entire screen for iOS...but I would really like to solve the matter conventionally (especially because this would not be acceptable on MacCatalyst and I would really love to avoid calculating runtime the space at my disposable on the view).

Comment: Moreover, when I try to add a new element in the list (maybe from the detail page) and I get back to loading data in the list, some of the items keep on being overlapped, even with 'HeightRequest' set to a specific value. You can see the update I posted. Additionally, just to be complete, when I changed it to `Grid` I didn’t set any `VerticalOptions` to it, so the problem seems to be within the `CollectionView` behavior when it fills any space.

Comment: @ImproveSoftware This fella Innova, has posted a question with exactly the same pictures as you. And is constantly trying to edit my post with comments. I accepted some small improvements, but this is not acceptable anymore. If you are colleagues, working on the same project, please use one account.

Comment: He has already stopped intervening. That question has been deleted as well. This is the only post about the matter so far. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: By the way, I had edited the post with some pictures showing an overlapping of items in the list. It was me, not Innova. The issue is still there!

Comment: @ImproveSoftware show me the current XAML. With the two row grid.

Comment: Take a look to the edit, please. Thanks.

Comment: @ImproveSoftware No. Remove the StackLayout. The outermost layout is the Grid itself. As I said Grid. Inside the Grid two columns. One column for filter, One column for CollectionView.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try asap. Maybe you intended two rows by the way, one for filter and one for `CollectionView` (just to benefit those who are reading the post).

Comment: @ImproveSoftware Yes, two rows. of course. Read my edit. I specify what to remove. If you ask me, 99.99% of the time, work in Grid.

Comment: Your solution works as expected. I have only one further question: what if the `CollectionView` is between two controls and the one on the bottom (e.g. `ActivityIndicator`) gets hidden by a `Binding` after data loading is complete? Using this approach, to make it work I need to assign a fixed height to the following controls, thus resulting in a no-sense empty space at the bottom of the `CollectionView` itself when those controls are hidden for any reason. Just wanted to understand if there's anything I can do about it.

Comment: @ImproveSoftware You use the word "auto" for this. You row definitions become: "40, *, Auto". Row0 control, Row1 CollectionView, Row2 indicator. You set your HeightRequest on your indicator. Row2 gets height when indicator is visible, and is 0 when not, so your CollectionView expands to bottom.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer but, unfortunately, setting other rows on the bottom of the `CollectionView` (to `auto` as you suggested of course) causes the issue to appear again. Apparently anything put **on the bottom** of the collection which **has no fixed size**, seems to upset the rendering of the grouped collection itself on iOS.

Comment: @ImproveSoftware can I see the new XAML you have?

Comment: I think is pointless. I just updated to the new Xamarin.iOS release, and the odd behaviors on iOS have multiplied. It has become a game-stopper to the project. Each and every `CollectionView` is endlessly expanding and doesn’t tolerate any other control below (hiding it). I tried both with `Grid` and expanded `StackLayout`, with no success.

Answer (score 1):

Having tried different approaches as suggested, I discovered that for the `CollectionView` to be dimensioned correctly and to avoid odd behaviors in group headers rendering, it can be nested into a `Grid` with `VerticalOptions = FillAndExpand`. This will let the `CollectionView` be scrolled to the end and will also allow any other control below to be shown as expected in the `View`.